# Change partial text in dropdown

Tags: jquery

my dropdown looks like this:

```
<select class="dropit">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.25">1.25</option>
<option value="1.5">1.5</option>
<option value="1.75">1.75</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2.25">2</option>
<option value="2.5">2</option>
```

Etc.

I have:

```
jQuery("select option:contains('.25')").text("&frac14;");
```

What I am trying accomplish:

```
<select class="dropit">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.25">1 1/4</option>
<option value="1.5">1 1/2</option>
<option value="1.75">1 3/4</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2 1/4">2</option>
<option value="2 1/2">2</option>
```

But I would like to use HTML fractions:
¼ for 1/4
½ for 1/2
¾ for 3/4

So my final dropdown would read:

1 ¼ (in HTML fractions)
1 ½

Etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&frac12;` is an HTML entity so it needs to be interpreted as html for it to be rendered properly. Here is my approach, it should work for all your current/future values assuming they follow the `...1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2...`  pattern.

```js
$("select option").each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  switch($this.val() % 1){
   case .25:
      $this.html(Math.floor($this.val()) + " &frac14;");
     break;
    case .5:
      $this.html(Math.floor($this.val()) + " &frac12;");
     break;
    case .75:
      $this.html(Math.floor($this.val()) + " &frac34;");
     break;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropit">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.25">1.25</option>
<option value="1.5">1.5</option>
<option value="1.75">1.75</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2.25">2</option>
<option value="2.5">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ah, got it. Once broken up as html, then I concatenate them together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var text=$("select option:contains('.25')").text()
text=text.substr(0,text.indexOf('.'));
$("select option:contains('.25')").html(text+"&frac14;")
```

HTML fractions are html tags not a text, so to render the html tags you have to use html() not text().